# Sortable column with custom data by date

Tags: custom-post-types, columns

I would like to sortable a column with custom data. I have a custom post type named "events" and I have a custom meta_key named "_start_at".

My column is sortable but when I click on, my posts are ordrered by date of publication and not by date "start_at".

How can i do this ?

This is my code :

```php
function my_set_sortable_columns( $columns )
{
    $columns['dateevent'] = 'dateevent';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_edit-event_sortable_columns', 'my_set_sortable_columns' );

function my_sort_custom_column_query( $query )
{
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

    if ( 'dateevent' == $orderby ) {

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => '_start_at',
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => '_start_at',
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set( 'orderby', '_start_at' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_sort_custom_column_query' );
```

Here it's an example of data for the _start_at meta value :
[image]

Comment: You need to assign `_start_at` as the **array key** for one of the arrays in your `meta_query` array. That's how we sort by a specific meta query clause.

Comment: I try to do this : '_start_at' => array('key'.... for the first and for the second array of meta_query array but it does not change anything...

Comment: What is the format of the `start_at` meta value? Can you give some sample values?

Comment: I added an example in my first message.Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Well, I suggest you to change the format to a standard MySQL date format like `Y-m-d H:i:s`. Because otherwise, sorting the values won't be easy. Did you use a plugin to add the meta; if so, what plugin?

Comment: OK I'll try to change the format. I used carbon fields to add this date field.

Comment: Thanks ! I change the format and I add the key to my array and it works ! I edit my first message with the code.

Comment: You're welcome, but remember that meta queries can make your site runs *very slow* once the dataset grows larger. But that's all I wanted to say about that, and actually, you should've posted an answer instead of editing your post, and then accept your answer later. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot to @Sally CJ for the answers. It works with changing format of start_at field and adding key in array like this :

```php
function my_sort_custom_column_query( $query )
{
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby' );

    if ( 'dateevent' == $orderby ) {

        $meta_query = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            '_start_at' => array(
                'key' => '_start_at',
                'type' => 'DATETIME',
            ),
        );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
        $query->set( 'orderby', '_start_at' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_sort_custom_column_query' );
```